# The PDF of this document has cut off several lines of text / readability issues

Tags: filing

For patent us20040167786: this specific patent's PDF is in "landscape" format, but it appears to have been perhaps written in the usual "portrait" mode.

The reason that this is noteworthy is that I am trying to do a very careful reading of this patent, only to find that several lines of its decriptive text (beginning at around page 87) can not be read. Therefore, I can not know every detail of this patent, and it is vital for me that I do not miss anything in it.

Is it possible to request a "portrait" version of the document, i.e. a document that does *not* have several lines of descriptive text cut out?

The patent can be found here: http://www.google.com/patents/US20040167786

If you view or download the PDF, and then jump to page 87+, you'll see that there appear to be lines of text that are excluded and not visible in the PDF format. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you retrieve the PDF from Espacenet http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/originalDocument?CC=US&NR=2004167786A1&KC=A1&FT=D&ND=3&date=20040826&DB=worldwide.espacenet.com&locale=en_EP you will find it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your problem correctly but I found http://www.freepatentsonline.com/20040167786.pdf to be OK.